# POO de un banco con python

Tags: python, poo

Estoy aprendiendo python y trato de resolver este ejercicio pero no se como avanzar. El enunciado es el siguiente:

Diseñar y codificar un modelo orientado a objetos de un banco donde hay cuentas
corrientes que tienen un titular y unos movimientos. Los titulares son clientes del banco.
Los clientes del banco pueden ser titulares de varias cuentas al mismo tiempo. Los
movimientos pertenecen a una sola cuenta. Para ello:

a) Crear la clase Cliente con los atributos __dni, __nombre y __apellidos.

b) Crear la clase Movimiento con los atributos __concepto y __cantidad. Los movimientos son inmutables.

c) Crear la clase Cuenta con los atributos __numero, __titular, __movimientos y
__saldo.

```
1) No se puede cambiar el número de una cuenta.
2) Se puede añadir un movimiento a una cuenta, pero no cambiar ni eliminar
   movimientos.
3) Tampoco se puede modificar directamente el saldo, sino que se debe actualizar
    directamente a partir de los movimientos que se realicen en la cuenta.
```

d) Crear un módulo principal.py que use las clases anteriores para representar un
modelo dinámico de objetos donde el cliente Antonio Martínez tiene dos cuentas
corrientes, cada una de ellas con tres movimientos. Imprimir por pantalla el saldo
actual de cada cuenta.
e) ¿Cómo se podría implementar la generación automática e incremental del número
de cuenta cuando se crea una cuenta nueva? Codiciarlo. (Indicación: Usar atributos
estáticos.)

Esto es todo lo que he podido hacer, aunque ni siquiera se si está bien. No se como añadir movimientos a la cuenta ni como calcular el saldo a partir de los movimientos.

De momento este es el código que tengo:

class Cliente:

```
def __init__(self, __dni,__nombre,__apellidos) -> None:
    self.set_dni(__dni)
    self.set_nombre(__nombre)
    self.set_apellidos(__apellidos)

def set_dni(self, dni):
    self.__dni = dni

def get_dni(self):
    return self.__dni

def set_nombre(self, nombre):
    self.__nombre = nombre

def get_nombre(self):
    return self.__nombre

def set_apellidos(self, apellidos):
    self.__apellidos = apellidos

def get_apellidos(self):
    return self.__apellidos

def __eq__(self, otro: object) -> bool:
    if type(self) != type(otro):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.__dni == otro.__dni
```

class Movimiento:

```
def __init__(self, __concepto, __cantidad) -> None:
    self.__concepto = __concepto
    self.__cantidad = __cantidad

def get_concepto(self):
    return self.__concepto

def get_cantidad(self):
    return self.__cantidad

def __hash__(self) -> int:
    return hash((self.__concepto, self.__cantidad))
```

class Cuenta:

```
def __init__(self, __numero, __titular, __saldo, __movimientos = None) -> None:
    self.__numero = __numero
    self.set_titular(__titular)
    self.__saldo = __saldo

    if __movimientos is None:
        self.__movimientos = {}
    else:
        self.__movimientos = __movimientos

def set_titular(self, titular):
        self.__titular = titular

def get_titular(self):
        return self.__titular

def get_numero(self):
    return self.__numero

def __hash__(self) -> int:
    return hash(self.__numero)

def get_saldo(self):
    return self.__saldo
```

Agradecería mucho su orientación para solucionar este ejercicio. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Son demasiadas preguntas; la idea es una pregunta x publicación. De todos modos, algunas observaciones para orientarte.

En la clase `Cuenta` debes usar una lista para los movimientos, no un diccionario. Una lista conserva el orden y acepta elemento repetidos. Es lo que se usa en el mundo real: cada nuevo movimiento se agrega al final de la cartola.

A la clase `Cuenta` también le falta una función para agregar movimientos, que recibe un movimiento y lo agrega a la lista:

```
def add_movimiento(self, movimiento):
    self.__movimientos.append(movimiento)
```

Para imprimir debes implementar el método `__str__()` en cada clase. Para la clase `Cliente`, el método sería:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.__dni} {self.__apellidos}, {self.__nombre}"
```

Lo que te piden de crear cuentas con movimientos se reduce a esto:

```
cliente = Cliente(123, "Antonio", "Martinez")
cuenta1 = Cuenta(13, 123, 0)
cuenta2 = Cuenta(14, 123, 0)
mov1 = Movimiento(501, 100)
mov2 = Movimiento(501, 150)
mov3 = Movimiento(421, 80)
mov4 = Movimiento(501, 120)
mov5 = Movimiento(300, 110)
mov6 = Movimiento(349, 130)
cuenta1.add_movimiento(mov1)
cuenta1.add_movimiento(mov2)
cuenta1.add_movimiento(mov3)
cuenta2.add_movimiento(mov4)
cuenta2.add_movimiento(mov5)
cuenta2.add_movimiento(mov6)
print(cliente)
```

produce:

```
123 Martinez, Antonio

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! En cuanto al saldo, como podría obtenerlo?

Comment: @arp. En el método `add_movimiento` tienes que incrementar/decrementar el saldo. Puedes usar valores negativos para indicar cargos.